# Dynamic value with like operator gets failed in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Dynamic value with like operator gets failed in mongodb.
Sample data in collection:

```
{ "_id" : 30, "item" : "box", "qty" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 40, "item" : "box1", "qty" : 50 }
db.mycollection.find({"item": /ox1/});
```

Its working.

```
$value = '/ox1/';
db.mycollection.find({"item": /$value/});
```

But dynamic value with like operator is not working. 
Please provide the solution if you have.

Answer (score 0):

In robomongo the following script works:

```
$value=/ox1/;
db.mycollection.find( {item: $value } );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @mu is too short : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074034/3933603,

the answer OP was seeking may be:

```
db.mycollection.find({"item": new RegExp($value)});
```

Answer (score -1):

tried this in comand prompt (Mongo shell) removing quotes around `/ox1/` it works.

```
$value = /ox1/;
db.mycollection.find({"item":$value});
```