# Using $regex mongodb query in node js not working

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

From node js, i trying to retrieve the documents based on the keyword with case-insensitive. When i try directly from the mongo db console , i am able to see the result.

```
db.users.findOne({"displayName":{$regex: /.*abc./, $options:"i"}})
```

But when i try the same in node js, i am getting empty result.

```
var selector = { "displayName": {$regex: "/.*abc./", $options:"i"}}
```

is this due to regular expression not in javascript.
Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073863/mongodb-regular-expression-search-starts-with-using-javascript-driver-and-node

Answer (score 33):

The [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) value needs to be either the string pattern to match or a regular expression object. When passing a string pattern, you don't include the `/` delimitters like you're doing in your node.js code.

So either of these would work in node.js:

```
var selector = {"displayName": {$regex: ".*abc.", $options:"i"}}
```

OR

```
var selector = {"displayName": {$regex: /.*abc./, $options:"i"}}
```

Answer (score 15):

could you please try this one, It works for me.

```
var getValue = "abc";

db.users.findOne({ displayName: new RegExp(regexValue, "i") }, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: this is the only one working for me `"mongoose": "4.11.2"`

Answer (score 5):

In mongodb console
try this query

`db.users.findOne({"displayName":{$regex: ".*abc", $options:"i"}})`

and in nodejs 
`var selector = users.find({ "displayName": {$regex: ".*abc", $options:"i"}})`

here users = is a collection name