# Mongodb nodeJS driver regular expression for any letter

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I have a very simple collection of 9 documents if I do this: 

`db.products.find({"Description": /.*m.*/}).count()`

it returns 3.

In node.js I have this:

`` db.collection("products").find({Description: new RegExp(`/.*${request.query.name}.*/`)}); ``

It behaves exactly as if I do:

`db.collection("products").find({Description: new RegExp(request.query.name})});`

I mean. I have to write an entire word to get results back. I should note that I have a $text index in the Description field and it is the only $text index in the collection.

The retrieve is very fast but... since I am using it in a autocomplete I was hopping to be able to write just one letter to start getting results. I project fields so the data returned is not too big. It works on the mongo console but it seems I am missing something in how Regex works in Javascript.

Many Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Following: [MongoDB Regular Expression Search - Starts with using javascript driver and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073863/mongodb-regular-expression-search-starts-with-using-javascript-driver-and-node) I have tried:

 `db.collection("products").find({Description: {'$regex': request.query.name}});`

with no avail. I still need to type a complete word. I insist that with a regex with a contains a letter works in the mongo shell.

I am really lost here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the **$options** property here. Like this:

```
db.collection("products").find({ Description: { '$regex': request.query.name, $options: 'is' }
});
```

**i**
- For case insensitivity.

**s**
- Will allow dot character to match all characters, and newline characters.

You can check more of this [MongoDB $regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html.).

I hope this helps.

Comment: did not work for me :(. If I do 

products = db.collection("products").find({Description: {'$regex':/.*m.*/, $options: 'is'}});


Works. But can't really get it to work with a variable. Am I *that* blind that I am missing something here and still cannot see it?