# $regex does not work in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know there is a lot of answers related `$regex`, but I tried everything for hours now and I can´t get this to work.

What I want is to find those `courses` which contain a letter "D" in the `courseName`. What am I doing wrong? Please help me!

I have the following document :

```
{
            "firstName": "Sarah",
            "lastName": "Jepsen",
            "age": 27,
            "courses": [
                {
                    "courseName": "Web-Development",
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "Santiago",
                            "lastName": "Donoso"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "courseName": "Databases",
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "Dany",
                            "lastName": "Kallas"
                        },
                        {
                            "firstName": "Rune",
                            "lastName": "Lyng"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "courseName": "Interface-Design",
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "Roxana",
                            "lastName": "Stolniceanu"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

And this is my find query :

```
student.findCourses = (fcallback) => {
    global.db.collection('students').find({ "courses.courseName": { $regex: "/D/" }, _id: false }).toArray((err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> student.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)
        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "student.js -> found -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
        return fcallback(false, jOk)
    })
}
```

Comment: you only have to remove the quotes around the pattern, like this: "$regex: /D/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the courses matching your regex, you'll have to filter them manually. Consider your case, with another `courses` array item:

```
{
    "courseName": "Unmatching", // no letter "D"
    "teachers": [
        {
            "firstName": "Dany",
            "lastName": "Kallas"
        }
    ]
}
```

your query would return it anyway, as other courses in the student document match your regex.

What you can do, is:

1. Query (`.find()`) for documents with matching course names
2. Filter them manually - loop through each item to check, if its name matches the regex

example data:

```
// 1
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a019896f89c24926108e2bf"),
    "firstName" : "Sarah",
    "lastName" : "Jepsen",
    "age" : 27,
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "courseName" : "Lorem",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "Ipsum",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "Dolor",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "Sit",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "Dolor 2",
            "teachers" : []
        }
    ]
},
// 2
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a019896f89c24926108e2be"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "age" : 22,
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "courseName" : "Dioptry",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "Dino",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "A",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "B",
            "teachers" : []
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "C",
            "teachers" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Query & filter code:

```
student.findCourses = (fcallback) => {

    var regexp = new RegExp('D');

    global.db.collection('students').find({ "courses.courseName": { $regex: regexp } }, { _id: 0, courses: 1 } }).toArray((err, result) => {

        // here, you'll receive:
        // [{ courses: [] }, { courses: [] }]
        // with all the courses inside
        // no matter if their names match the given regex
        // as it's enough that one of them does
        // to return the whole document

        // filtering:
        var filtered = result.map(student => {
            student.courses = student.courses.filter(course => regexp.test(course.courseName));
            return student;
        });

        // now, your filtered has exactly the same format
        // [{ courses: [] }, { courses: [] }]
        // but only with courses matching the regexp inside it

        console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered);

        // what you can do to get flat courses array is:
        var flat = filtered.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c.courses), [])

        console.log(JSON.stringify(flat));


        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> student.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)
        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "student.js -> found -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
        return fcallback(false, jOk)
    })
}
```

Comment: I applied your solution and with some minor corrections it works.

Comment: NOTE: u defined regexp and then u used regex,  also the `{ "courses.courseName": { $regex: regexp }`should be closen here like this `{ "courses.courseName": { $regex: regexp } }`and not after the projection.

Comment: Could you explain a bit the part `var flat = filtered.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c.courses), [])`? What p and c stands for?

Comment: `p` stands for `previous`, `c` stands for `current` (array item). First `reduce()` argument is a function applied to every item in an array, and second (`[]`) is the initial value of `p` ( - `previous`). So, we start reducing with `[]` as `p`, conacatenating `current` element. And so on, for every element. Read more: [MDN Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
global.db.collection('students')
    .find({ "courses.courseName": { $regex: new RegExp('D') }, _id: false })
```

I think the MongoDB client understands either a RegExp or a string literal pattern, but I think you may be mixing two different patterns here. If you put `"/D/"` you're looking for a course which contains the literal `/D/` in the name, not just `D`.

Related: [MongoDB Regular Expression Search - Starts with using javascript driver and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073863/mongodb-regular-expression-search-starts-with-using-javascript-driver-and-node)

Edit:

What is `_id: false` for? If you're trying to do a projection (and remove the `_id` field), your syntax is incorrect. The `{ _id: false }` should be passed as a second parameter to `.find()`. Your current query is matching for the regex and also checking that `_id` is equal to `false`.

```
global.db.collection('students')
    .find({ "courses.courseName": { $regex: /D/ } }, { _id: false })
```

Comment: I see your point and I applied the changes but still does not work.

Comment: @codeDragon I noticed something else you may want to try

Comment: Now it finds the whole object, by applying this change.

Comment: If extra fields are coming back in the response than you want, then you can exclude more of them in the projection in the same way that `_id` is excluded. e.g. `{ _id: false, 'courses.teachers': false }`

Comment: If you only want certain fields returned, you can specify `1` or `true` for the fields in the projection instead, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/ and if you need help it may be appropriate to ask a new question on that topic

Comment: Does not this looks right now? `global.db.collection('students').find({ "courses.courseName": { $regex: /D/ } }, { "courses.courseName": true, _id: false }).toArray((err, result) => {}`

Comment: Using this, if I search for a letter which is in only any of the courses it returns me all of them , and not only the course containing that letter.